# Is there an alternative/workaround for `boot2docker save`?

Tags: macos, docker

Currently there seems to be a bug in boot2docker in OS X that essentially wipes the boot2docker custom setup after restarting the Mac: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/834

So I am wondering if before restarting the Mac, I can manually save aside some file that after the restart I could simply load it, so that I won't lose my boot2docker setup.

Additionally, I would like to better understand the proper way of using the `save` command.

It seems that if I `boot2docker up` > `boot2docker ssh`, I cannot use `boot2docker save`, I have to first `exit` and only then I can use it. Or, I can open another Terminal instance and use it there... but what's the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution/workaround is to save the state of the VM using the software used to run it (in the case of boot2docker that is VirtualBox).
After a restart you can then simply load the saved state and things will continue to work as before.